# Como fazer um metodo no controlador Spring que faça o mesmo que esse metodo de um servlet?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

Esse codigo devolve um json para uma pagina html que usa um recurso ajax para carregar um chart da API do Google
Gostaria de fazer o mesmo mas usando um controlador do Spring!

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<Student> listOfStudent = getStudentData();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonString = gson.toJson(listOfStudent);

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        response.getWriter().write(jsonString);

    }
```

Esse trecho de codigo foi retirado desse  [site](https://dzone.com/articles/drawing-google-chart-servlet).

Eu gostaria muito de fazer isso usando o spring com o thymeleaf!

Aqui esta o treixo de minha pagina que chama o controlador:

```
   <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/student/jsonData}">Chart Student</a></li>
```

Criei essa classe:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int computerMark;
    private int  mathematicsMark;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getComputerMark() {
        return computerMark;
    }

    public void setComputerMark(int computerMark) {
        this.computerMark = computerMark;
    }

    public int getMathematicsMark() {
        return mathematicsMark;
    }

    public void setMathematicsMark(int mathematicsMark) {
        this.mathematicsMark = mathematicsMark;
    }
```

Aqui esta a classe controlador que tentei fazer mas não funciona:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentJsonData {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsonData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView showChart() {

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("student/visualization-chart-demo");

        List<Student> listOfStudent = getStudentData();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonString = gson.toJson(listOfStudent);

        view.addObject("jsonString", jsonString);

        return view;
    }

    private List<Student> getStudentData() {

        List<Student> listOfStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setName("Sandeep");
        s1.setComputerMark(75);
        s1.setMathematicsMark(26);
        listOfStudent.add(s1);

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setName("Bapi");
        s2.setComputerMark(60);
        s2.setMathematicsMark(63);
        listOfStudent.add(s2);

        Student s3 = new Student();
        s3.setName("Raja");
        s3.setComputerMark(40);
        s3.setMathematicsMark(45);
        listOfStudent.add(s3);

        Student s4 = new Student();
        s4.setName("Sonu");
        s4.setMathematicsMark(29);
        s4.setComputerMark(78);
        listOfStudent.add(s4);

        return listOfStudent;
    }
}
```

No arquivo js do artigo modifiquei apenas essa linha de todo o codigo:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/springsecurity/student/jsonData",
...
...
```

Esse é a minha pagina onde queria renderizar o chart:

```
<html
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Google Visualization Chart Demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="student-bar-chart"></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script  th:src="@{/resources/js/visualization-chart-script.js}" ></script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Decididamente estou fazendo uma confusão nesse meu controlador!!
Coloquei o atributo produces = "application/json" porque quero devolver um json.Já pesquisei isso em todo o lugar e não encontrei como fazer! Já tentei de tudo , mas não consigo exibir o chart na pagina!! 
Certamente deve ser o problema o meu metodo do controlador, pois na aplicação atraves do menu eu o chamo o metodo que retorna uma view que é a pagina onde eu quero exibir os dados, e essa pagina tem o arquivo js que tem o jquery que  possui o ajax que usa a url que eu modifiquei do arquivo para chamar /springsecurity/student/jsonData.

Acho que esse é o ponto onde eu me perco.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acho que agora eu  descrevi tudo o que tentei fazer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tende senguindo o exemplo abaixo.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/student")
public class StudentJsonData
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsonData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String jsonData()
    {
         List<Student> listOfStudent = getStudentData();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.toJson(listOfStudent);
    }

    private List<Student> getStudentData() {

        List<Student> listOfStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setName("Sandeep");
        s1.setComputerMark(75);
        s1.setMathematicsMark(26);
        listOfStudent.add(s1);

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setName("Bapi");
        s2.setComputerMark(60);
        s2.setMathematicsMark(63);
        listOfStudent.add(s2);

        Student s3 = new Student();
        s3.setName("Raja");
        s3.setComputerMark(40);
        s3.setMathematicsMark(45);
        listOfStudent.add(s3);

        Student s4 = new Student();
        s4.setName("Sonu");
        s4.setMathematicsMark(29);
        s4.setComputerMark(78);
        listOfStudent.add(s4);

        return listOfStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, por sua resposta.